# How to check network connectivity in qt on mac os?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, networking

I am using c++ in qt.
I want to check network connectivity without ping to sever(like "google.com").

I did it for Windows.

```
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    DWORD flag;
    if(InternetGetConnectedState(&flag,0))
    {
        result = true;
    }
    else
        result = false;
#elif defined(Q_OS_MAC)
#endif
```

But I don't know How to do it on mac os.

How can I do it?

Comment: Connectivity to which network?  There are many.

Comment: I just want to check internet connection.

Comment: Have a look at [`QNetworkInterface`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkinterface.html).